# adding python loop best practices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to learn the best way to learn to code. I am practicing with some simple code that asks for 2 numbers and multiples them and I want to add a a function to ask if you are done or if you want to multiply some more numbers. Below is the code I started with. I want to know what is the best way to have it loop back to asking for 2 more numbers with a yes or no question?

```
    #Ask for number to be multiplied
    num1 = input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: ").strip()
    num2 = input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: ").strip()

    #Convert input to interger
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    #Multiply the numbers
    results = num1 * num2

    #Print the results
    print("Your answer is: " + str(results))
```

Comment: love the way you add comments, keep it up. Just use a `while True:` type of loop structure and ask for your question at the end, or you can wrap the code in a function and call it over and over if the user inputs yes at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a reminder like when the user is finish then make you can make the reminder is `False` to make it finish or take a `input` and check if user want to `exit` then just simply break the loop.

```
# set reminder for while loop
done = False

while not done:
    #Ask for number to be multiplied
    num1 = input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: ").strip()
    num2 = input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: ").strip()

    #Convert input to interger
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    #Multiply the numbers
    results = num1 * num2

    #Print the results
    print("Your answer is: " + str(results))
    ask = input('Do you want to try again y/n: ')
    if ask == 'n':
        done = True # set the reminder is true or break the loop
        # break
```

Answer (score 0):

While loop is the most used one:

```
repeat = 'yes'
while repeat.lower() == 'yes':
    #Ask for number to be multiplied
    num1 = input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: ").strip()
    num2 = input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: ").strip()

    #Convert input to interger
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    #Multiply the numbers
    results = num1 * num2

    #Print the results
    print("Your answer is: " + str(results))
    print('If you want to continue type yes or no')
    repeat = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by wrapping the whole code in a `while True` loop with a `break` statement to exit. Essentially, we will want to repeat the process forever, until the user types `n` or `N`. The check condition can be refined as desired.

```
while True:
    # Ask for number to be multiplied
    num1 = input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: ").strip()
    num2 = input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: ").strip()

    # Convert input to interger
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    # Multiply the numbers
    results = num1 * num2

    # Print the results
    print("Your answer is: " + str(results))

    # Ask to continue or not
    res = input("\nWould you like to continue? (y/n) ").strip()
    if res.lower() == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking to do!

Comment: Thank you. There really is no need to use additional control variables with a loop as simple as this. A `while true -> break` structure is all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple use while loop and declare a variable named `choice` and ask the user to enter his choice.

```
while(True):
    choice = input("Would you like to continue? (y/n) ")
    if(choice.lower=='y'):
        num1 = int(input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: "))
        num2 = int(input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: "))
        results = num1 * num2
        print("Your answer is: ",results)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def termination():
    _noexit=str(raw_input())


    if _noexit.lower() == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False    


#Cal the termination condition
while termination:

    num1 = input("\nEnter the first number you want to multiply: ")
    num2 = input("\nEnter the second number you want to multiply: ")


    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    results = num1 * num2
    print results

    #Checking termination
    termination()
```